# Number of arrangements of squares on a square grid

Tags: combinatorics

In how many ways can one put 4x4 and 2x2 tiles on a grid of 8x8 squares (matching the grid lines) such that

- no two tiles overlap
- the 4x4 tiles can only be moved in steps of length 2

What can be very easily seen are the following numbers $f(N,M)$ of ways of arranging $N$ 4x4 and $M$ 2x2 tiles on the grid:

$f(N=1,M=0) = 9$

$f(N=0,M=1) = 49$

$f(N=4,M=0) = 1$

$f(N>4,M) = 0$

$f(N=0,M=16) = 1$

$f(N,M>16) = 0$

What I search for is

$F = \Sigma_{N\leq 4,M\leq 16} f(N,M)$

or at least its order of magnitude.

Comment: If I create a $4\times4$ tile by putting ogether four $2\times 2$ tiles, must this be counted as "different way", or is the only parameter to differentiate two combinations the resulting "image"?

Comment: It must be counted as different ways.